# Change iframe content with Bootstrap button click and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to change iframe src url from bootstrap button click.
The javascript code works with traditional button, but something goes wrong when I use the same code to change the iframe with jquery:
(I also would like the iframe to get random at page load)

**bootstrap element (html page)**

```
...
<div class="col-md-6">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="randomize">sekvanta ekzerco</a>
</div>

<div>
    <iframe id="question" src="url0" width="275"
                            height="650" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
</iframe>
</div>

...
    <script src="application.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

**application.js**

```
var sources = new Array()

sources[0] = 'url0'
sources[1] = 'url1'
sources[2] = 'url2'
sources[3] = 'url3'

var p = sources.length;

$(document).ready(function(){
    var randomSource = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));
    $('#question').attr('src', 'sources[randomSource]');
}

$('#randomize').click(function() {

    var randomSource = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));
    $('#question').attr('src', 'sources[randomSource]');
}
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes arround the `sources[randomSource]`.

Comment: What do you mean by: " The javascript code works with traditional button" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the single quotes from `sources[randomSource]` as the browser will interpret it as a literal rather than evaluate the expression.

```
$('#question').attr('src', sources[randomSource]);
```

**Full snippet:**

```js
var sources = new Array()

sources[0] = 'url0'
sources[1] = 'url1'
sources[2] = 'url2'
sources[3] = 'url3'

var p = sources.length;

$('#randomize').click(function() {
    var randomSource = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));
    console.log(sources[randomSource]);
    $('#question').attr('src', sources[randomSource]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="randomize">
Click me
</button>

<div id="question">
</div>
```

JSFiddle demonstrating the Bootstrap version.

https://jsfiddle.net/fz6yythy/